# julia eval an expression including an escape variable

Tags: julia, expression, eval, metaprogramming

Using eval against the following expression is straightforward:

```
exp = :(x + 1)
x = 1
eval(exp)
```

I cannot figure out how to evaluate the following expression that involves an escaped variable:

```
x = 1
exp = :($(esc(x)) + 1)
```

A dump of the exp gives:

```
head: Symbol call
args: Array{Any}((3,))
  1: Symbol +
  2: Expr
    head: Symbol escape
    args: Array{Any}((1,))
      1: Int64 1             <-- current value of x
  3: Int64 1
```

I figured out how to replace the escaped variable value like this:

```
exp.args[2].args[1] = 2
```

`dump(exp)` is now:

```
head: Symbol call
args: Array{Any}((3,))
  1: Symbol +
  2: Expr
    head: Symbol escape
    args: Array{Any}((1,))
      1: Int64 2            <-- Replaced value
  3: Int64 1
```

I am missing one last step that I could not find in spite of searching the docs and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want to accomplish, however `esc` normally makes sense only inside macros, so if have object like this you need to wrap it around a macro.

```
julia> exp = :($(esc(x)) + 1)
:($(Expr(:escape, 33)) + 1)

julia> macro call_exp(); exp; end
@call_exp (macro with 1 method)

julia> x=33;

julia> @call_exp
34
```

Comment: Well, I assume that @somemacro evaluates the expression inside the macro somehow. It's more about getting in the guts of how the while thing works rather than achieving something in particular. I am trying to understand how expressions are created, evaluated, scoped and so on. So, I would love having a solution that bypasses the use of a macro.

Comment: The documentation for `?esc` explicitly states `Only valid in the context of an Expr returned from a macro` hence I guess you can only use it in macro